# How to set scroll height to array length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a function with main purpose to slice an array to the length I need and this function loads more items from the array if the bottom or top is reached.

Mainly it is done to limit the amount of React components to render, so we won't need to render as many components as the lenght of the array.

So now I need to add scrollbar to the parent component, so it would move if the bottom is reached and new items from the array are added. But the problem is that this parent component has always a fixed scrollHeight as we only render 5 components and we only change data.

Is there a way to set scrollHeight to a length of the array?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you need to move the parent component all the way down. I think basically what your are trying to accomplish is Load more logic, to display certain number of items within a container.

Here is an [example](https://dev.to/debosthefirst/how-to-create-a-load-more-button-in-react-1lab) from Adebola that might help.